# Minimum width for a photon

Tags: visible-light, photons, frequency, wavelength

First direct unpolarized 500 wavelength light through the narrowest slit possible so that the exiting photons are all polarized parallel with the slit. Beyond that place another slit perpendicular so that no photons will pass. My questions are: (1) If the second slit is slowly opened, at what width would photons begin to pass through? 
(2) In what way does wavelength effect this?
(3) Does the minimum width of the first and second slit change proportionately with the wavelength? My guess is the difference between the two widths would increase as the frequency got higher. 
Are there studies on this that you can direct me to. Thanks

Comment: The picture you are describing in which photons pass through or are blocked by a slit is not quite accurate. One should think instead about an electromagnetic wave focused onto a slit, in which case the wave will have some component that is reflected and some component that is transmitted and undergoes some diffractive effects (if the slit size is similar to the wavelength). If you want to think about individual photons, you can think of each photon as having the same wave-like form of the whole wave, so each photon has some reflected portion and transmitted portion (until measured).

Comment: Whether you believe in photons or not the question can be answered. The question is about slit width sizes And proportionality compared to each other.